# Alternatives to the classic bottle/bucket method for raiding?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am in a hardcore raiding guild on world of warcraft and we are required to be online every monday and tuesday for extreme raiding. These raid sessions last about 14 hours each and we do not take breaks. our raid leader has suggested that we use buckets if we have to use the bathroom and while that's been effective and easily disposable I would much rather find a more preferable alternative that would eliminate the smell. What are some good alternatives that I could use that are economic and efficent that would make raiding more enjoyable?

Comment: I would honestly just suggest joining a less hardcore raiding guild but that is just me.

Comment: I've never played Wow and I always thought the whole "peeing in a bucket" thing was a joke. I've learned something new today.

Comment: How to relieve yourself isn't a gaming problem. The fact you're gaming while its needed still doesn't make it a gaming problem.

Comment: This has to be a troll.  There's no way.

Comment: @SouthpawHare sadly there are people that actually play MMOs like that.

Comment: @Ramirez As far as WoW goes these days, it's really hard to spend 14 hours straight raiding unless you *really* try. I can see current Heroic-level or Mythic-level raids *maybe* taking up to 3 or 4 hours (at which point, any competent raid leader can recognize you're slamming your head against a brick wall) but a 14 hour long raid requires you to be both playing with no hands, blindfolded, and perhaps not even using a computer.

Comment: Makes me really enjoy my Final Fantasy 14 weekly raids which may take me about an hour or two to finish about 6 of them.

Comment: @Ramirez Yeah, but you're not counting the hours spent doing the storyline to open up the raids. :P

Comment: **No** guild raids 14h without bathroom break, that is just absoolutely silly. The "raid bucket" is a myth. Yes, its often used, yes, its joked about, but its not something anyone would *actually* do. And if they do, they need medical help. There is dozens of ways to get your bathromm break. After a wipe, don#t run back. Go to the bathroom. At most places, it takes ~60s to run back in. So let a fellow healerr ressurect you instead of running and go to the toilet in the meantime. If you need substantially more then a minute to pee then do it more often, for smaller times.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is going to be very much life advice.

My recommendation would be just to **join a less hardcore guild.** What you are doing by putting yourself through 14 hours of gaming every Monday and Tuesday is **not healthy** especially without breaks. You should be gaming to have fun, if you are told that you aren't allowed to have breaks while playing you have the right to leave and find somewhere that is less extremist. You yourself said you wanted to make raiding more enjoyable, well the simple fact if you are not enjoying this "extreme raiding" you should leave and find someplace better. Trust me when I say this putting yourself at risk for a few in game virtual items is **not a good way to live**.

Simply put, find a guild that is a bit more casual about raiding if you enjoy raiding, you'll have a much better time, and keep your dignity intact.

Answer (score -1):

I havent played world of warcraft in a long time, but some advice about raiding - if you're seriously hard core about doing it for that long of a time you need to just do all your bathroom stuff in advance and spend those two days effectively fasting. This in the long run can actually be healthy for your body as fasting is a good way to train your metabolism and boost your energy levels while losing weight and detoxing your body.